# Which file i have to place when child during child theme creation?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I had created a child theme. So i want to know some basic question about child theme.

1) i had create a child theme.If i am updating the theme, What should be happened ? I mean all customization which i had does manually is remain there in parent theme after updating the Parent theme.

2) After creating child theme i have to place all file of the parent theme in which i had made the customization in child theme or not ?

3) Suppose in child theme there are three files 
functions.php 
style.css 
screenshot

Now if i am activating this child theme is there any difference of look and feel of activating parent theme and child theme. 
i am asking these because i am facing these issues.

and i want to make sure for testing my child theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if you change your child theme, the customization of the parent theme remains there in wordpress cause the parent theme is the same
2. in a child theme wordpress search the file first in the child theme folder, then, if not found, goes to the parent theme (is the same to all files, except functions.php that not overrides the parent theme functions cause is loaded in addition)
3. if you active a child theme takes all the functions of the base themes but with the files in the child theme is like and object that extends another

More info in: [Child themes Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

**TIP**: using [template partials](http://kovshenin.com/2013/get_template_part/) could be useful to work with child themes

Comment: i mean i am updating the parent theme.now the customization which i had done previously on parent theme that has remain in parent theme after update the parent theme?

Comment: by customization you mean the options, widgets, menus and sidebars?